# Android NDK cmake disable undefined symbols checking for only one library

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, linker, clang

I use noise suppression APIs from OpenSL lib on android and seems it is not included in older NDKs prebuilt OpenSL library. So I got errors like "undefined reference to `SL_IID_ANDROIDNOISESUPPRESSION'". I think this is r17c NDK issue because I have not such errors on r21b. But currently I can not update NDK version for my big legacy crossplatform project. So I want to disable undefined symbols checking while linking to OpenSL ES library on android. I know how to do this for entire project for example from gradle (-DANDROID_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=TRUE) but is there possibility to do this only for OpenSL library or at least for my cmake audio module (described in separate cmake file and included in main project).
I'm not very good at cmake and clang linker flags. Trying to do this second day without success(

There is how I include OpenSL on android:

```
target_link_libraries(my_audio
PRIVATE
android
log
atomic
OpenSLES)
```